# CORS 'null' is not the same origin as 'null'

Tags: html, server, cors, client

I have a strange issue with CORS. I'm making a request from a file and my issues started today, before it was working (and it's still working on firefox). But on chrome i get an issue where it says that the 'null' origin is not allowed on server side. But it is If i check the network i can see this:

```
Response
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTION
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null
Connection: close
Content-Length: 21
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 29 Mar 2018 10:10:53 GMT

Request
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Authorization: Basic somePasswordHere
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
```

The 'somePasswordHere' i modified right now before posting it's actually the username and password in basic auth.

And strangely i get this in my console on chrome: `The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'null' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

If i check on my server i can see that i get a request from a null origin and i allow it i can see that there are credentials and stuff and that the actuall cal is processed correctly, but on chrome side i get this message anyway.

And strangely enough it work on firefox (usually it's the other way around).

Any ideas? Do i have to add another header for chrome or something?

PS: I can see chrome updated yesterday tho so it may have broken something.

PS2: Another strange thing in the "response preview" in the network tab i can actually see the content is correct and it's there... but the message 'origin supplied different than...' is still there dahell?

Answer (score 1):

`null` is interpreted as a literal host origin (address), and should be not put into `Origin` header. This header should contain the hostname from which the request is started.

For the same reason, If you want to allow all origins, try to put `*` instead of `null` into `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header of the response.

As you may know, each CORS request is actually made of two requests: the *preflight* request (which is always sent) and the actual request (which is sent only if preflight request succeeds).Maybe Chrome detects `null` as special keyword and not as a host name, and blocks the request. Firefox could be a bit more permissive and understands the intended behavior.

Comment: I can't put '*' because i want credentials. I put the 'null' inside a string before putting it in the header aswell.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, I was speculating that maybe `null` isn't anymore a valid hostname in newer versions of Chrome. What happens if you put another string (or the real hostname) into the headers?

Comment: The app is made using Angular and when making the query when working with angular it work (angular host the apps on localhost:4200). And my server correctly allows this to go through aswell. It's once it's compiled to run from a file it doesn't work. And if i host the file on iis server it works aswell. I'm afraid chrome did add this in their new update and don't allow null origin anymore and firefox will probably follow...

Comment: It is not correct that "each CORS request" includes a preflight request. Many types of CORS requests do not require preflight, so they are sent to the server and then your browser decides whether to show the response to the requesting script.

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer,

After reading a little bit about cors i've found out that the 'null' origin souldn't work on firefox. The browser's hide the origin before sending it to the server so it's not actually 'null' but 'file://'.

So the correct way to allow 'null' origin for a file is : `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'file://'`

And this worked.

I don't know why chrome decided to do this only now and they left my app working for months. Anyway with this change i'm back to normal.